Is it correct to create a new instance of sqlalchemy engine for each request?
I started to develop a bigger application that needs persistance.
Currently I have a Database class that contains the necessary methods to manage table creation/dropping. Retrieves sessions and creates the engine.
class Database:
    """
    Database class that manages the database setup and sessions.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            database_url = config.get("database_url")
            if database_url:
                self.engine = create_engine(
                    database_url,
                    pool_size=config.get("pool_size"),  # Max number of connections
                    pool_timeout=config.get("pool_timeout"),  # Time until a connection fails
                )
                self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
            else:
                raise Exception("database_url not found.")
        except Exception as err:
            raise err

    def get_session(self):
        return self.Session()

    def create_tables(self):
        """
        Creates all tables in the database.
        """
        try:
            Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)
        except Exception as err:
            raise err

    def drop_tables(self):
        """
        Drop all tables in the database.
        """
        try:
            Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=self.engine)
        except Exception as err:
            raise err

Although I don't know if this is the best python way to this I have a few question related to the use of this class.
Inside my router.py I have a dependency injection inside a POST endpoint. This dependency is defined as:
def get_db():
    return Database()

So, this basically creates for each request a new Database() instance, is this correct? What are the best practices for doing this?
What is the best way to initialize the database inside my main.py?
Thanks!

I see the FastAPI tag so I will assume that framework. Generally, you want to create an Engine instance at the application level, and avoid doing anything which looks like self.db = db. Use that Engine in a get_db function to yield a sessionmaker and use that in your endpoint DI dependency. This creates a context for each request that automatically cleans up and makes rollback convenient. Don't couple your table creation/drop to your engine, just have separate helper functions. Better yet, use a migration tool like Alembic.

Thanks for the answer. So you recommend me instead of having a class dedicated to the db manage, just have separated db functions so I don't need to need to do self.db = db and separate creat/drop? I'm used to think in POO that's why my first approach was "create a class Database."

A better approach would be to implement a database client with a session factory inside and use it like this:
class DatabaseClient:
    """Database client."""

    def __init__(self):
        """."""

        async_engine = create_async_engine(
            self.build_url(),
            isolation_level=CONFIG.DB_ISOLATION_LEVEL,
            echo=CONFIG.DB_ECHO,
            pool_recycle=CONFIG.DB_POOL_RECYCLE,
            pool_size=CONFIG.DB_POOL_SIZE,
            max_overflow=CONFIG.DB_MAX_OVERFLOW,
        )
        self.session_factory = async_scoped_session(
            sessionmaker(
                autocommit=False,
                autoflush=False,
                bind=async_engine,
                class_=AsyncSession,
                expire_on_commit=False,
            ),
            scopefunc=current_task,
        )

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def get_session(self) -> AsyncContextManager[AsyncSession]:
        """Create new async session."""

        session = self.session_factory()

        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            await session.close()


class ItemRepository:
    """Item repository."""


    def __init__(self, db: DatabaseClient):
        """."""

        self.db = db

    async def get_item(self, item_id: UUID4) -> Item:
        """Get item by id."""

        async with self.db.get_session() as session:
            return (
                await session.execute(...)
            ).scalar()


There is a remark in SQLAlchemy docs that 'SQLAlchemy generally does not recommend the “scoped” pattern for new development': https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#using-asyncio-scoped-session

I think the best way is to create the Database instance in the lifespan and store it to the state. Then get_db_session dependency can get the instance of Database from request.state and create session.
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import Annotated, cast

import fastapi
from fastapi.datastructures import State
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session


config = {
    "database_url": "sqlite://",
}

# The Database class' code here is just to make this code example runnable.
# This part of code just copied from the question.
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            database_url = config.get("database_url")
            if database_url:
                self.engine = create_engine(
                    database_url,
                    # pool_size=config.get("pool_size"),  # Max number of connections
                    # pool_timeout=config.get("pool_timeout"),  # Time until a connection fails
                )
                self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
            else:
                raise Exception("database_url not found.")
        except Exception as err:
            raise err

    def get_session(self):
        return self.Session()


class MyState(State):
    db: Database


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: fastapi.FastAPI):
    db = Database()
    yield {"db": db}


app = fastapi.FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


def get_db_session(request: fastapi.Request):
    state = cast(MyState, request.state)
    with state.db.get_session() as session:
        yield session


@app.get("/")
def index(session: Annotated[Session, fastapi.Depends(get_db_session)]):
    pass


Why are you catching Exception just to re-raise? Why are you catching database init connections at all? Usually if your app tries to start and you cannot connect to the database, the whole app is SNAFU. Might as well let it crash hard and get a traceback.

My intention was to show how to create Database instance in lifespan and create a session taking db object from request.state. I just copied the part of Database class' code to create a runnable code example. In fact, I absolutely agree, try-except block is not needed there
